# Laravel - How to collect grandchildren

Tags: php, laravel

I am looking to pickup all the IDs from grandchildren as follows:

A->hasMany(B)->hasMany(C)->[C->ids]

I would like to eloquently get all IDs from C, how would I go on to do that? I can't find that in the docs.

> EDIT: I did try `A->with(['B.C'])->get()` But I only got a collection in the size of C, I can't see any relations of C (or B) in the collection, only A

Comment: Can you post your relationships so we can provide working code examples for you? But basically, if your relationships are setup you can `A::query()->with(['B', 'B.C'])->b->c->get()->pluck('id');`